# How to get smooth animation in SkiaSharp

Tags: animation, xamarin, skiasharp

I am trying to achieve smooth animation using Xamarin SkiaSharp. The core issue is the the time between calling canvasView.InvalidateSurface(); and hitting the mathod OnCanvasViewPaintSurface to do the redraw can vary from 3 to 30 ms which gives a somewhat jerky appearance when you are moving an object across the screen. I have tried to mitigate this by adding a dead loop in the draw code, which helps some but is not a great solution. I do not understand why the time varies so much, and I do not see any way around this. You cannot put a sleep in the draw code. How do games achieve smooth animation? My code follows

```
    async Task DoAnimationLoop()
    {
        while (DoAnimation)
        {
            AccumulatedTime = StopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5));

            if (AccumulatedTime > 50)
            {
                StopWatch1.Restart();
                MoveItems();
                SKCanvasView canvasView = Content as SKCanvasView;
                TotalBounds = new Size(canvasView.Width, 
                                       canvasView.Height);
                canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, 
                                          SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        AccumulatedTime = StopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        while (AccumulatedTime < 30)
        {
            AccumulatedTime = StopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        e.Surface.Canvas.Clear();
        e.Surface.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Background, 0, 0);

        foreach(Item item in AllItems)
        {
            e.Surface.Canvas.DrawBitmap(item.CurrentBitmap, 
            item.CurrentPositionX, item.CurrentPositionY);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:
From experience, I get the smoothest animations with SkiaSharp by creating SkiaSharp SKCanvasViews that have Bindable properties that can be incremented with Xamarin.Forms.Animate. Animate handles all the timing and sleeping code based on variables you configure it with. As you want a loop, you can set the `repeat` delegate to return true when calling `Animate.Commit( ... repeat: () => true ...)`

Here is a method example that animates a progress bar "filling" to 100 percent (without looping), by incrementing the `ProgressBar`'s `PercentageFilled` Property. Note the timing settings you can configure: Refresh `rate = 11ms` (equates to "90 fps": 1000ms/90 = 11.11), `timeToAnimate` is the length of time the animation should take to complete in ms, and you can choose from several easing functions.

```
        private void AnimateProgressBar()
    {
        double startPercentage = 0; //start at 0 percent
        double endPercentage = 1; //fill to 100 percent (Forms.Animate will evenly increment
        //between 0 and 1 , and in this case the ProgressBar's OnPaintSurface method knows how to draw based
        //on the given decimal i.e. if PercentageFilled is .5 it will draw the bar to
        //50 percent of its possible max length)

        uint timeToAnimate = 1000;

        Xamarin.Forms.Animation animation = new Animation(v => _ProgressBar.PercentageFilled = (float)v, startPercentage, endPercentage, easing: Easing.CubicOut);

        animation.Commit(_ProgressBar, "FillPercentage", length: timeToAnimate, finished: (l, c) => animation = null, rate: 11);

    }
```

When the `PercentageFilled` Property is changed it triggers `InvalidateSurface` by placing a call to `InvalidateSurface()` within the `OnPropertyChanged` method. To do this override `OnPropertyChanged` like so in your `SKCanvasView` derived class:

```
 class ProgressBar: SKCanvasView
    {     
         //...
public BindableProperty PercentageFilledProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PercentageFilled), typeof(float), typeof(ProgressBar), 0f);

    public float PercentageFilled 
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(PercentageFilledProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(PercentageFilledProperty , value); }
    }


    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        
        InvalidateSurface();
    }

 protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    { 
      //Draws progress bar based on the PercentageFilled filled property 
    }
           //....
}
```

In the question's code it appears that a lot of items are being moved (`MoveItems();`) in sequence and this technique of drawing items one by one moving might be the cause of jitter? But MoveItems appears to be the place where you might want to use Forms.Animate that is you could Create a `Forms.Animation` with `MoveItems()` as the `Callback`. Look into the microsoft documentation for "[Custom Animations in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom)" for more info on how to animate with callbacks.

Also check out "[The basics to create custom Xamarin.Forms controls using SkiaSharp](https://medium.com/@k.l.mueller/the-basics-to-create-custom-xamarin-forms-controls-using-skiasharp-be24bdda879e)" by Konrad Müller on Medium which contains this helpful paragraph which might be useful to consider if you are making a game:

> The basic SkiaSharp.Views.Forms provides two views you can use as a
> base for your controls: SKCanvasView and SKGLView. The CanvasView uses
> the CPU accelerated backend while the GLView uses OpenGL and therefore
> the GPU. You might intuitively think that using the GPU for graphics
> operations is always the better choice but in fact, OpenGL has a high
> overhead when creating the GL context. The CanvasView simply allocates
> the memory it needs and as long as enough CPU power is available, it
> can render without problems. In theory, the CanvasView should be
> better suited for less demanding renderings and GlView better for
> complex renderings but the power of modern smartphones makes these
> differences mostly unnoticable. I would recommend to simply stick to
> the CanvasView and switch to the GlView if the rendering gets to
> complex and you notice performance problems.